# Delete and Copy Big Table with Autoincrement

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I want to delete many rows (More than a million) from a big table.

My table is like this:

```
Create table MY_TABLE (
MY_ID           NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (Start with 1) primary key,
PROCESS         NUMBER,
INFORMATION     VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Instead of using "delete from MY_TABLE where PROCESS = 3"

I do:

```
CREATE TABLE BCK_MY_TABLE AS (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE PROCESS <> 3);
DROP TABLE MY_TABLE;
RENAME BCK_MY_TABLE to MY_TABLE;
```

Problem is: When i create another table (BCK_MY_TABLE) i lose the autoincrement on the column MY_ID. What can i do?

Comment: try recreating the table with the original ddl, new name, then using INSERT AS SELECT to copy the data you want to keep over. You'll have to have the identity column be cool with the id value being provided on the insert, so on null vs by default

Comment: you'll lose all column defaults.  its just the nature of CTAS.  So add them back in after rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward way to do this with 'create table as select' (CTAS), because `my_id` in the new table won't be an identity column, and you can't make existing columns into identity columns.

One way would be to create the table explicitly with an identity column, copy the data and reset the identity value:

```
create table bck_my_table
( my_id           number generated by default as identity primary key
, process         number
, information     varchar2(100) );

insert into bck_my_table (my_id, process, information)
select my_id, process, information from my_table;

alter table bck_my_table
modify my_id generated always as identity start with limit value;
```

(We have to use `generated by default` so the column is updatable, then change it to `generated always` to prevent further changes.)

Another way would be to copy the table using CTAS then add a new identity column, update it from the old `my_id`, reset it using `start with limit value`, drop the old column and rename the new one.